# Run command 2 regardless of whether command 1 succeeds or not

Tags: bash

I have `cmd1` and `cmd2`.

`cmd1 && cmd2` will not run `cmd2` if `cmd1` fails.

`cmd1 || cmd2` will run `cmd2` if `cmd1` fails

How do I run `cmd2` regardless of whether `cmd1` succeeds or not?

Answer (score 34):

To execute `cmd2` regardless of whether the previous one result is, separate your command with semicolons or newlines:

```
cmd1; cmd2

# or
cmd1
cmd2
```

If [`set -e`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) is enabled, add `|| true` to ignore the result of the preceding command:

```
set -e

cmd1 || true; cmd2

# or
cmd1 || true
cmd2
```

Comment: You can also use `cmd1 & cmd2`. This way `cmd2` won't wait for `cmd1` to finish before running.

Comment: The suggestion does not work when the bash script has `set -e` enabled. In this case one can do `cmd1 || true; cmd2`. (Replace `;` with new line if needed.)