# Is 'cmd1 [newline] cmd2' as concurrent as 'cmd1 & cmd2' in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, background-process, parallelism

Does the following script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

while true
do
  ab -c 700 -n 100000000000 -r http://crimea-post.ru/ >>crimea-post & ab -c 700 -n 100000000000 -r http://nalog.gov.ru/ >>nalog
done
```

do exactly the same as

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

while true
do
  ab -c 700 -n 100000000000 -r http://crimea-post.ru/ >>crimea-post 
  ab -c 700 -n 100000000000 -r http://nalog.gov.ru/ >>nalog
done
```

From my experience the first script creates `nalog` file sooner (within seconds) than the second script (after more than 10 minutes) which suggests to me that the latter waits for `ab -c 700 -n 100000000000 -r http://nalog.gov.ru/ >>nalog` to finish. It should not be the case because from [what I've researched so far](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232714/run-command-2-regardless-of-whether-command-1-succeeds-or-not?) the second script is meant to start `ab -c 700 -n 100000000000 -r http://nalog.gov.ru/ >>nalog` without waiting for `ab -c 700 -n 100000000000 -r http://crimea-post.ru/ >>crimea-post` to finish.
I want the two said `ab` commands to execute concurrently, how might I accomplish this in Bash?

P.S. It is `&` and not `&&`. I know what `&&` does and did not want to apply it here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `cmd1 [newline] cmd2` is not as concurrent as `cmd1 & cmd2` — the former waits for `cmd1` to complete before starting `cmd2`.

If you want execution to continue while the first command runs, you need to keep the `&` when splitting this over two lines:

```
ab -c 700 -n 100000000000 -r http://crimea-post.ru/ >>crimea-post & ab -c 700 -n 100000000000 -r http://nalog.gov.ru/ >>nalog
```

becomes

```
ab -c 700 -n 100000000000 -r http://crimea-post.ru/ >>crimea-post &
ab -c 700 -n 100000000000 -r http://nalog.gov.ru/ >>nalog
```

If you want to ensure both commands complete before looping again, you can use `wait`.

Other shell constructs also provide concurrency, notably pipes: `a | b` (or its variant in some shells, `a |& b`, to redirect both output streams¹) runs `a` and `b` concurrently, and waits for both to complete before continuing. Some shells also support coprocesses (see [How do you use the command coproc in various shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86270/86440)) and process substitution (see [How do you use the command coproc in various shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86270/86440)) which can be used to run commands concurrently.

See [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/86440) for details of the list terminators (which include `&`) and pipe operators.

---

¹ Except in ksh, where it runs `a` as a coprocess.

Comment: Note that in ksh, `a |& b` is like the `coproc a; b` of `zsh` / `bash`, which is different from the `a |& b` of csh / zsh / bash (though still run `a` and `b` concurrently)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas aargh, there’s always more variants to deal with...

Comment: That "canonical answer" is geared towards the bash shell (as it says in the introduction) and POSIX sh though, it's not covering the many more operators found in some other Bourne-like shells such as ksh93 or zsh nor the corresponding operators of non-Bourne-like shells.

Comment: Good point, and providing detailed coverage of all that would make the answer more complex and therefore less useful.